# How can I see CRASHES & ANRS for a wear app

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, android-anr-dialog

I have developed an android watch face. 
Under the google play console there is a tab for **CRASHES & ANRS**.

From what I read in the documentation and in some SO questions these reports are automatically created when the app crashes.

But from my experience so far that does not happen for a wear application.

What do I need to do or am I missing something?

Comment: The dialog pops up asking you whether you wanna send the crash report or not (on a mobile device at least), I do not know if it's the same for android watch. User can opt not to send crash report tho, that might be what they've done.

Comment: @Vucko thanks for the info but the issue is worse. Actually there is no way so far to get these reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to do this. The Play Store team is aware of this request, but have not yet released support for it.

Comment: Is there a issue tracker for this ?